# Why am i not getting neumorphic design in react native?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement neumorphism to a login form..But I am not getting any shadow...Here is my code:
jsx:

```
<View style={styles.topShadow}>
   <View style={styles.bottomShadow}>
      <View style={styles.loginForm}>
          ....
      </View>
   </View>
 </View>
```

stylesheet.create:

```
topShadow: {
    marginTop:100,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: -6,
      height: -6,
    },
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity:1,
    shadowColor: '#1e1e39',
  },
bottomShadow: {
    shadowOffset:{
      width:6,
      height:6
    },
    shadowOpacity:1,
    shadowRadius:6,
    shadowColor:"#2e2e55"
  },
loginForm: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
  },
```

Where exactly am i going wrong?

Comment: what is the style definition for `loginForm`?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: you are only showing the style definitions for `topShadow` and `bottomShadow` but not `loginForm`

Comment: yeah i made those edits now

Comment: I made a simple example with your styles and I can see the shadow: https://snack.expo.dev/@tromgy/view-function-component-example

Comment: I wonder why the shadow isn't appearing in my form...